# Facebook cookie 'expires' attribute has a different format from that specified in RFC 2109

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I was just viewing the cookies Facebook has set in my browser, when I noticed that the value for the `expires` attribute is in a format different from that specified in the RFC 2109. The default standard is `;expires=Weekday, DD-MON-YY HH:MM::SS GMT`, like **;expires=Friday, 15-Mar-07 12:00:00 GMT**. However, FB is using something like **06 October 2012 20:42:03**. How come it is being considered legitimate by the browsers?

[image]

Comment: Whoever has voted to close it, please explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, FB is using something like 06 October 2012 20:42:03.

No, that’s just how *your* browser is *displaying* the date to you.

Use Firebug or a similar tool, and have a look at the original HTTP Response Headers – and you’ll see that Facebook uses the date format as it is defined for cookies: `Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT`